# Paint-Event is not triggered after calling Control.Refresh()

Tags: c#, .net, events, user-controls, paint

Can anyone tell me why the paint event doesn't get triggered, after I call Refresh(), Invalidate(), or Update() on a UserControl (in my case a PictureBox)?

Judging from the description, it should call the paint event as it repaints itself, or am I wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards
Simon

Edit:

I set the global variable _card1 to a Windows Metafile (.emf) and then call picturebox.Refresh(). The metafile is displayed perfectly directly at the beginning when the Paint-Event is triggerd ONCE. After that it is never triggered again (tested via the Visual Studio Debugger by Setting a breakpoint).

```
private void card1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_card1, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, pb.ClientSize));
}
```

Comment: You mean a Custom Control. Yes, `Invalidate()` will cause a call to `OnPaint`. `Refresh()` is `Invalidate(false) + Update()`. Post your code.

Comment: _it should call the paint event_ and it surely does. Show you code and the layout..

Comment: Normally this occurs in Net when you using a DataSource for a control.  The trick is to set the DataSource to null and then back to the object.  So pictureBox1.DataSource = null; pictureBox1.DataSource = myImage.

Comment: @jdweng  The PictureBox Control doesn't have a DataSource property. The OP is referring to an `Invalidate()` method call which appears not to call the OnPaint method / raise the Paint event.

Comment: @Jimi : You do not understand the issue.  The OP is saying he changed the picture in the picture box and the picture is not changing.  And the Refresh/Invalidate isn't working.

Comment: @jdweng Question Tags: `events`, `paint`. Question Title: *Paint-Event is not triggered after calling Control.Refresh()*. Question content: *Can anyone tell me why the paint event doesn't get triggered, after I call Refresh(), Invalidate(), or Update()*. The `PictureBox.Image` property is not mentioned anywhere. Are you commenting on the wrong question?

Comment: for the code: see the edit above.

Comment: The OnPaint method is called (raising the Paint event) when it's required or when you call `Invalidate()`, to cause a Control to repaint itself. In *static* conditions (nothing *obscures* your PictureBox, the Form is not Minimized/Maximized, moved outside the Screen bounds etc.), the Control doesn't need to be repainted, so it never receives a `WM_PAINT` message, so it doesn't call its OnPaint method, so the Paint event is not raised.

Comment: Notes: there a re no *global variables*, you probably mean an Instance Field (or a Public Property, you didn't say where this Image comes from). When/how you call Refresh() is unknown. Is this actually a Custom Control (a Control derived from PictureBox)? What is the purpose of this Control? What behavior is different from what is expected.

Comment: What would a variable declared as "private Metafile _card1" directly in the class be, if not a global variable or an instance filed (is there a difference? a global variable imho is of course also instance bound)
There is no custom control. Only a simple WindowsForms Picturebox, to whose Paint-Event I've registered an EventHandler, which only gets called once and displays the initial Metafile-Image perfectly. It just doesn't get called a second time to change the image. I click on the picturebox, change the variabel and then I call the refresh.

Comment: In my opinion the behaviour should be -> Call picturebox1.Refresh -> Paint Event gets triggered and executes my code. But the event doesn't get triggered. Do I understand something wrong here?

Comment: What calls `Refresh()`? On what object? Post the complete code that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: The click event handler on the picture box calls the refresh. But I am coming to understand the problem, it has something to do with the initial image being undefined or null, if I define the initial image, it works perfectly. So the issue for me would be closed, I still have absolutely no idea why it doesn't work, if the initial image is null, but since it works know. I don't really care anymore. But thanks anyway for all your time and effort. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the control.visible property is set to false.
This is what I experienced. After I re-set .visible = true, the problem resolved.

Try this, good luck for you!